# Java JCR/Adobe AEM: How do I access the node directly without using queries?

Tags: java, aem, jcr

as above. I've looked at "getNode" (part of javax.jcr.node) and it requires a relative path. I'm hoping there's a function that I haven't seen yet that accepts an absulate path.

Code example:

```
Node node = Node.getNodeByAbsulotePath("/content/my-folder-here/my-node-here");
```

Comment: I think the documentation is misleading. AFAICT [javax.jcr.Node#getNode(String)](https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/spec/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Node.html#getNode(java.lang.String)) accepts absolute paths fine. It just _also_ accepts relative paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `javax.jcr.Session` object, to access the repository. It has the wanted `session.getNode(absPath)` method.

Every Node-object has a backlink to its session, therefore you can either traverse forward the node-structure via `node.getNode(relPath)` or just get the session via `node.getSession()`.

see:

https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/spec/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Session.html#getNode(java.lang.String)

or the JackrabbitSession:

https://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/2.12/org/apache/jackrabbit/api/JackrabbitSession.html

Comment: Session is what I'm after. I had an existing code somewhere which uses it but I cannot remember what class or function I used. The first thing that came to mind what the getNode. Thank you.